# How can i see the number of orders placed by every customer in a specific day chosen by the employee?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
import uuid  # GET A RANDOM ID FOR THE CUSTOMER
from datetime import date  # GET CURRENT DATE

TodayDate = date.today()
Dates = {}
```

My idea is with the Dates dictionary to save and print how many orders in total were placed on a specific day chosen by the employee

```
Customers = {}

FirstEmployeeAccountUsername = "coffee1"
FirstEmployeeAccountPassword = "coffeeshop1"
SecondEmployeeAccountUsername = "coffee2"
SecondEmployeeAccountPassword = "coffeeshop2"
ThirdEmployeeAccountUsername = "coffee3"
ThirdEmployeeAccountPassword = "coffeeshop3"

print("Welcome to our coffee shop!")
print("Login")

# EMPLOYEE LOGIN PROCESS STARTS
LoginEnter = True
while LoginEnter:
    username = input("Username: ")
    password = input("Password: ")
    if username == FirstEmployeeAccountUsername and password == FirstEmployeeAccountPassword or username == SecondEmployeeAccountUsername and password == SecondEmployeeAccountPassword or username == ThirdEmployeeAccountUsername and password == ThirdEmployeeAccountPassword:
        print("Login Successful")
        LoginEnter = False
    else:
        print("Invalid Login. Try again")
# EMPLOYEE LOGIN PROCESS ENDS
```

Here I get how many orders a specific customer has placed in total

```
# PROCCESS AFTER ORDER PLACEMENT STARTS
while True:
    CustomerName = input("Customer's Name:")
    CustomerAddress = input("Customer's Address:")


    if CustomerName in Customers:
        Customers[CustomerName]['Orders'] += 1
    else:
        Customers[CustomerName] = {}
        Customers[CustomerName]['Address'] = CustomerAddress
        Customers[CustomerName]['ID'] = uuid.uuid1()
        Customers[CustomerName]['Orders'] = 1


    print("This customer has ordered {} time(s)".format(Customers[CustomerName]['Orders']))

    print("Current Date is: {}".format(TodayDate))
    OrderPrice = input("Total amount of order:")
```

This is the output i am currently getting : [image: Output of code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the same logic you did for counting orders for customers when you place an order. You can use date.toordinal() for the dict key, this will return an integer representing the date: `TodayKey = date.toordinal(date.today())`

before order placement:

```
if TodayKey not in Dates:
    Dates[TodayKey] = {}
```

in each order:

```
if CustomerName not in Dates[TodayKey]:
    Dates[TodayKey][CustomerName] = 1
else:
    Dates[TodayKey][CustomerName] += 1
```

Comment: Have i done something wrong? This error shows up https://prnt.sc/vold0g and I have wrote `TodayKey = date.toordinal(date.today())` at the top

Comment: my bad, it should be `if CustomerName not in Dates[TodayKey]`, emphasis on the `not`. it is throwing an error because it is attempting to access Dates[TodayKey][CustomerName] without previously creating the key, value pair

Comment: Ok now supposedly the employee wants to see how many orders were placed yesterday? how do i do that

Comment: the key for yesterday is just `TodayKey - 1`.

Comment: when i type print(TodayKey - 1) the output is 737751 for some reason

Comment: yes. `date.today()` returns a `date` object. python Dicts do not support using objects as keys, which is why I used `date.toordinal(date.today())` as the key instead. this returns an ordinal (integer) representation of the date. in order to translate the ordinal back into a date object for yesterday, you can use `date.fromordinal(TodayKey - 1)`. take a look at the datetime docs if you need more clarification about the specifics: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=date#date-objects

Comment: Ok thanks a lot , i havent worked with dictionaries yet , only with lists I am still trying to understand dicts